# Let's Encrypt Cert is valid, but it still is not secure

Tags: azure, lets-encrypt

I've a couple of ASP.net websites hosted on Azure and I've installed Let's Encrypt Cert for them.
When accessing one of them, although it has a valid Let's Encrypt certificate, on some customers' machines it syas the connection is not secure.
The ceriticate is definietly valid but Chrome,Firefox and Edge all say it's not secure:

[image]

What can cause this? The machine date/time is current.

The website is secure if I check it on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: https://docs.certifytheweb.com/docs/kb/kb-202109-letsencrypt/
R3 intermediate CA was expired on September, maybe some of the clients' trusted CAs are updated and revoked that intermediate CA.

You can use this website to validate this:
https://docs.certifytheweb.com/docs/kb/kb-202109-letsencrypt/